# html align 3 div 'form-group' boxes together : bootstrap-3.3.0

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this html form. it has phone number, ic number(has 3 boxes in 1 row), and company name.
when the zoom is ZERO, the phone number+ICnumber+company are All aligned in one line.  When I increase/reduce the zoom, the ic number box is no longer aligned with the phone number box and company name.

How do I get all 3 to be aligned together?

**correction** : apologise for wrong tagging, using bootstrap-3.3.0.min.css

```
                <!-- show phone number -->
               <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="registerphonenumber" type="text" th:field="*{phoneNumber}" class="form-control block-centered login-input" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors txt-centered"></div>
                </div>

                 <!-- show IC NUMBER -->
                <div class="form-group" style="color:#0000FF; margin-left:160px;" >

                   <input type="hidden" id="fullIc" th:field="*{icNumber}" maxlength="6" size="6" required/>


                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <input type="text"
                        placeholder="YYMMDD" id="myKadA" maxlength="6" style="width:90px !important" onchange="checkMyKad()" size="8"  class="form-control block-centered ic-input" required>                        
                        -
                        <input type="text"
                        placeholder="PB" id="myKadB"  maxlength="2"  style="width:60px !important" onchange="checkMyKad()" size="2" class="form-control block-centered ic-input" required>                        
                        -
                        <input type="text"
                            data-equals="test"
                            placeholder="####" id="myKadC" class="control" style="width:60px !important" onchange="checkMyKad()" 
                            maxlength="4" size="10"
                            class="form-control block-centered ic-input" 
                            required>
                    </div>

                    <p style="text-align:left" class="notice-on-error" id="myKadErrorMsg"></p>

                    <div class="help-block with-errors txt-centered"></div>
                </div>

               <!-- show company name. -->
               <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="registerCompanyName" type="text" th:field="*{userProfile.companyProfile.companyName}" class="form-control block-centered login-input" placeholder="Company">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors txt-centered"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Why are you using the large left margin and fixed input widths?

Comment: Read the docs on form layout: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-grid

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The 3 boxes in the ic number block get aligned veritcally,not side by side

Comment: You can as well use col-sm to force them to be inline

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:lavender;">phone number</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">IC NUMBER</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:lavender;">company name</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: There is no `col-xs-` in Bootstrap 4 and the using `sm`,`md` and lg for the same col size is unnecessarily redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code below:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4"> One of three columns </div>
     <div class="col-md-4"> One of three columns </div>
     <div class="col-md-4"> One of three columns </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/